# Jersey Client java.util.List<POJO> automatic converter

Tags: jersey

I have a resource like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/todos") 
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Cliente> getListagem() {
```

And my jersey client is:

```
ClientResponse response1 = wr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);
List<Cliente> colecao = response1.getEntity(List.class);
```

It's generated erros
**Grave: A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type interface java.util.List, and MIME media type application/xml was not found**

I wonder why the jersey became the List in XML and the client can not automatically convert it?
What is best way to fix this?
Regards..

Answer (score 3):

Try this on the server:

```java
public JResponse<List<Cliente>> getListagem() {
  List<Cliente> response = ......;
  return JResponse.ok(response).build();
}
```

And this on the client:

```java
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/service");
List<Cliente> colecao = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get( new GenericType<List<Cliente>>() {} );
```

Comment: How would the client to get the listing?

Comment: You don't have to modify the type on server.  That client code works for me.